# Ext.Create and this.callParent

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How can I use `Ext.create` and `this.callParent` together? If I use following code I will get errors retrieving data from an ajax store.

```
items: [
    { xtype: 'combo',
        initComponent: function() {
            ...
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The `callParent` docs say:

> Call the "parent" method of the current method. That is the method previously overridden by derivation or by an override (see Ext.define).

In other words, you only get callParent within `Ext.define` or `Ext.override`; not when you override this method in a config.

What is really important to understand is that `initComponent` was not meant to be overridden as a config. You should really extend the `combo` class and override `initComponent` there.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use `boxReady` event in listener config.

```
Ext.create('...', {
    listeners: {
        boxReady: function() {
            //Do something with this...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with the original question.

Comment: In my case I need a function where I can use Ext.create. If I do this in config, all instances have the same instance of Ext.create. And this method should be called only once.